# AFNetworkReachabilityStatus com valores incoerentes ao restabelecer conexão

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, redes, afnetworking

Eu estou tentando usar o framework RestKit para observar as mudanças na conexão através do método `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock` da classe `AFHTTPClient`. Assim que o aplicativo é iniciado eu recebo o valor `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi`, e quando a conexão com a internet é desativada eu recebo o valor `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable`. Mas quando a conexão é restabelecida, na maioria das vezes eu continuo recebendo `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está falando de RestKit ou de AFNetworking?

Bom, vamos as duvidas.

`SCNetworkReachability` serve para você monitorar seu status de rede, ele não pode dizer para você se um host está online ou offline, mas pode dizer se está "reachable", isso claro, se seu network (e não o device), consegue acessar o host.

Uma das coisas que vejo por ai é o pessoal usar o `SCNetworkReachability` ou `Reachability` (que é uma abstração do `SCNetworkReachability` desenvolvida pela Apple), para testar uma conexão de rede para depois disparar uma requisição para um serviço remoto.

Ao meu ver, isso é uma total perda de tempo, já que desta forma, seu app demorar mais para requisitar um serviço e o usuário espera mais. Além de que, o status de rede pode mudar no intervalo entre o teste e o disparo da requisição de fato.

Se caso você esteja usando `SCNetworkReachability` ou `Reachability` para testar o network para depois disparar uma consulta, recomendo você fazer o contrário, dispare a consulta mesmo sem saber se tem networking ou não e faça o tratamento de erros depois.

[Este post](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/102712223177/correctly-implementing-network-reachability-on-ios) mostra como usar esse approach corretamente.

Em outro caso onde você queira apenas, exibir o status de networking na tela por exemplo, use sem problemas o `SCNetworkReachability` ou `Reachability`.

Espero ter ajudado.